# what does direct in _meta.get_field_by_name(django) mean

Tags: django, meta

I don't understand what "direct" is used for.

i did some google research about _meta.get_field_by_name, and found 
[Given a QS field lookup key, how to find fields type across joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260539/given-a-qs-field-lookup-key-how-to-find-fields-type-across-joins)

but what does "the ORM's lookup" mean in django?

Answer (score 0):

From the population of the `_name_map` attribute on Django `Options` object in `django.db.models.options`, it looks like it is tied to whether the field name you are using is a field declared in your `Model` or a name created from a `related name` set up. I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with the related name stuff but the code looks like:

```
for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
    cache[f.field.related_query_name()] = (f, model, False, True)
for f, model in self.get_all_related_objects_with_model():
    cache[f.field.related_query_name()] = (f, model, False, False)
for f, model in self.get_m2m_with_model():
    cache[f.name] = (f, model, True, True)
for f, model in self.get_fields_with_model():
    cache[f.name] = (f, model, True, False)
for f in self.virtual_fields:
    if hasattr(f, 'related'):
        cache[f.name] = (f.related, None if f.model == self.model else f.model, True, False)
```

So you can see only the first two for-loops populate the cache with entries that have `direct` as `False` and they use `related_query_name`. Maybe someone else can shed more light on it or more likely in the 2 & 1/2 years since you asked, you've figured it out for yourself :)